# Azure Api Management Join Payloads and to provide customer

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a question about the use of the Azure Management Api. The architecture of the single responssabilidade Api predicts domain to perform the functions of the business area. See image structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMmH.png)

**1. I wonder if the Azure Api Management operates as a management or I have the possibility of using it as a Geteway add results of many APIs in one (
orchestrating) and available to the client that made the request?**

**2. The responsability to gather this data is the Web Application?**

**3. Is there a pattern?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure API management can do both, it started as a management tool, but has received some updates so it can act as a gateway as well.

Read about the different API managment policies you can create here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-policy-reference/

Or take a look at the advanced policies, with the `control flow` and the `send request` 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn894085.aspx

For an example of sending requests to gather information from multiple sources see this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/api-management-sample-send-request/